# Trying to link a .c file with a .s file, but I get "Illegal instruction"

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, arm, illegal-instruction

I have these two files, 9-main.c and 9-mult.s.

**9-main.c** :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mult(int);

int main(){
        int result = mult(5);
        printf("Result: %d\n",result);
        return 0;
}
```

**9-mult.s** :

```
.global mult

mult:
        mov     r1,r0
        lsl     r0,r0,#4
        add     r0,r1,r0
        bx      lr
```

I am trying to link them:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 9-main.c 9-mult.s
```

But if I execute a.out:

```
$ ./a.out 
Illegal instruction
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: I assume that you attempt to run the program on the target system? If you run in a debugger, where does it stop?

Comment: Your assembly code looks like Thumb code. Is your C code compiled to ARM code or Thumb code?

Comment: @Michael ARM32. I don't know what thumb code is

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't tried with a debugger, I am trying to learn and I don't know how to use it

Comment: What is ARM32? Which specific ARM architecture are you targeting (i.e. ARMv5, ARMv7, etc)? Thumb is the more compact instruction set available in a separate mode on some ARM processors.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my Raspberry Pi 2B.  What system do you run your code on?

Comment: @fuz does it work in your raspberry pi? also, my raspberrypi is 64 bit and I have kali installed. I had to installed the 32 bit toolchain "gnueabihf" to be able to compile in ARM32

Comment: @Mnkisd Interesting.  Unfortunately I cannot test this on the setup you describe right now due to a lack of surplus computers.

Comment: Could it be that your Kali Linux is for soft-float ARM and thus the program crashes in floating point code?

Comment: @fuz but my program doesn't use floats... btw, again, does it work in your raspberry even if you have not kali installed?

Comment: @Mnkisd `printf` and the C runtime code might use the FPU.  Yes, it does work on my Raspberry Pi, but it's a RPi 2B (32 bit only) and runs FreeBSD.  Which Kali Linux image did you use exactly?

Comment: re4son kernel. one question: what does the program do when you execute it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221254/discussion-between-fuz-and-mnkisd).

Comment: Long before you started writing arm assembly language you needed to get the arm documentation, in that documentation you see the arm instructions and the thumb instructions, really no reason to not know what thumb is/means.  You really need to stop now, get and skim over that document, before working on these assignments or asking questions here, we are not here to read the docs for you.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to get the arm documentation and learn the instruction set.

You should disassemble your program to confirm.  The first question is are you cross compiling this on an x86 and then trying to run ARM on x86?  I think you would get a different error.  Next is it an a.out file format issue, that may be primitive so trying to run aarch32 in aarch64 mode and would be bad instructions or...

For armv7-a compatibility mode on a 64 bit arm (armv8...) if told that or built for that the gcc compiler will default to thumb/thumb2 mode.

```
int mult(int);
int fun ( void )
{
    return(mult(5)+1);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e96d 3e02   strd    r3, lr, [sp, #-8]!
   4:   f04f 0005   mov.w   r0, #5
   8:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <mult>
   c:   f100 0001   add.w   r0, r0, #1
  10:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
  12:   bf00        nop
```

then as written

```
.global mult
mult:
        mov     r1,r0
        lsl     r0,r0,#4
        add     r0,r1,r0
        bx      lr
```

will default to arm unless specified otherwise on the command line (which it wasn't)

```
00000000 <mult>:
   0:   e1a01000    mov r1, r0
   4:   e1a00200    lsl r0, r0, #4
   8:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

because mult is not marked as a function label in the eyes of gnu linker then when you link it

```
00002000 <fun>:
    2000:   e96d 3e02   strd    r3, lr, [sp, #-8]!
    2004:   f04f 0005   mov.w   r0, #5
    2008:   f000 f804   bl  2014 <mult>
    200c:   f100 0001   add.w   r0, r0, #1
    2010:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
    2012:   bf00        nop

00002014 <mult>:
    2014:   e1a01000    mov r1, r0
    2018:   e1a00200    lsl r0, r0, #4
    201c:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
    2020:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

boom, there is your fault.  bl to mult without a trampoline means it is in thumb mode and now it is trying to execute those bytes as thumb instructions not arm.  It might survive for a while but will eventually fault.

(Frant has confirmed this for you, assuming this is the path you took to this particular fault)

So you have a few choices, can read Frant's answer:

```
.global mult
.type   mult, %function
mult:
        mov     r1,r0
        lsl     r0,r0,#4
        add     r0,r1,r0
        bx      lr
```

Tell the tools that mult is a function label, re-assemble and re-link:

```
00002000 <fun>:
    2000:   e96d 3e02   strd    r3, lr, [sp, #-8]!
    2004:   f04f 0005   mov.w   r0, #5
    2008:   f000 e804   blx 2014 <mult>
    200c:   f100 0001   add.w   r0, r0, #1
    2010:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
    2012:   bf00        nop

00002014 <mult>:
    2014:   e1a01000    mov r1, r0
    2018:   e1a00200    lsl r0, r0, #4
    201c:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
    2020:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Because it is an armv7 we got the blx thumb2 extension, if I specify armv4t across the project then we get the trampoline I was expecting.  Both are fine depends on the instruction set, and armv4t will work on the aarch32 compatibility mode side of the 64 bit processor.

```
00002000 <fun>:
    2000:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
    2002:   2005        movs    r0, #5
    2004:   f000 f80c   bl  2020 <__mult_from_thumb>
    2008:   3001        adds    r0, #1
    200a:   bc10        pop {r4}
    200c:   bc02        pop {r1}
    200e:   4708        bx  r1

00002010 <mult>:
    2010:   e1a01000    mov r1, r0
    2014:   e1a00200    lsl r0, r0, #4
    2018:   e0810000    add r0, r1, r0
    201c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00002020 <__mult_from_thumb>:
    2020:   4778        bx  pc
    2022:   e7fd        b.n 2020 <__mult_from_thumb>
    2024:   eafffff9    b   2010 <mult>
```

The linker adds the mult_from_thumb trampoline to convert between thumb mode and arm mode.  bx lr can handle mode switches so you don't need a trampoline on the way out only on the way in.

Your other option would be to build mult as thumb

```
.thumb
.global mult
mult:
        mov     r1,r0
        lsl     r0,r0,#4
        add     r0,r1,r0
        bx      lr

00002000 <fun>:
    2000:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
    2002:   2005        movs    r0, #5
    2004:   f000 f804   bl  2010 <mult>
    2008:   3001        adds    r0, #1
    200a:   bc10        pop {r4}
    200c:   bc02        pop {r1}
    200e:   4708        bx  r1

00002010 <mult>:
    2010:   1c01        adds    r1, r0, #0
    2012:   0100        lsls    r0, r0, #4
    2014:   1808        adds    r0, r1, r0
    2016:   4770        bx  lr
```

But this would fault if called from arm mode code.

With gnu assembler you can use .type...function or .thumb_func, to make this more correct.

```
.thumb
.global mult
.thumb_func
mult:
        mov     r1,r0
        lsl     r0,r0,#4
        add     r0,r1,r0
        bx      lr

00002000 <fun>:
    2000:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
    2002:   2005        movs    r0, #5
    2004:   f000 f804   bl  2010 <mult>
    2008:   3001        adds    r0, #1
    200a:   bc10        pop {r4}
    200c:   bc02        pop {r1}
    200e:   4708        bx  r1

00002010 <mult>:
    2010:   1c01        adds    r1, r0, #0
    2012:   0100        lsls    r0, r0, #4
    2014:   1808        adds    r0, r1, r0
    2016:   4770        bx  lr
```

Same machine code so the .thumb would have made it work dumb luck, but declaring the label as a function is as important as declaring it as global.  With the .type you can put that wherever like you can with .globl but .thumb_func has to be before the label, not immediately but basically the next label it finds it will mark as a function.

So after

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 9-main.c 9-mult.s -o myprog.elf
```

while you are learning asm, and even sometimes when not, certainly if you are mixing languages you should always follow that with:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -D myprog.elf
```

and examine the output.

Can use lowercase -d for just the code, uppercase -D will also include the data sections which are often as important to see that it built what you wanted it to build.

To complete asking your question I recommend you disassemble and post the main function and the mult function to see if it is an interwork problem.  Or did you instead try to run an arm binary on an x86 or something like that?

Frant has shown a more verbose set of directives, if you examine the full output of the compiler

```
    .cpu cortex-a72
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 2
    .eabi_attribute 34, 1
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "so.c"
    .text
    .align  1
    .p2align 2,,3
    .global fun
    .arch armv8-a
    .arch_extension crc
    .syntax unified
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .fpu softvfp
    .type   fun, %function
fun:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    strd    r3, lr, [sp, #-8]!
    mov r0, #5
    bl  mult
    add r0, r0, #1
    pop {r3, pc}
    .size   fun, .-fun
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 10.2.0"
```

You will see among other things the .type function.  They double dipped here and did both the .type and .thumb_func which makes sense, this is an algorithmically driven output.

Comment: If you know your whole project is one mode, arm, or thumb, say working on a cortex-m based mcu, then you can get lazy and not declare all of the labels as functions, although you need to for the ones that are in the vector table (on a cortex-m, different target, different rules, than your raspberry pi).

Comment: He is running an Aarch32 Linux executable on a Linux AArch64 system (Kali Linux on  a RaspberryPi 3) augmented with Aarch32 libc/libc++ libraries.

Comment: ahh, right so the cross compiler is to cross from aarch64 to aarch32

Comment: sorry I failed to use .type function in prior answers where I showed a C/asm mixture.

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling/executing in a non-trivial environment for a beginner: compiling/linking/executing a mix of `aarch32` C/assembly code on a `aarch64` system.

I would suggest to start specifying which architecture you are assembling for as well as the exact instruction set you are using - this is useful information for people who want to help - and to use some standard directives for defining functions in GNU AS assembly language, the way they would be generated by the gcc compiler:

```
        .arch armv7-a            // target architecture is armv7-a/Aarch32
        .fpu vfpv3-d16           // specify available floating-point hardware
        .syntax unified          // use unified assembler syntax
        .arm                     // generate 32 bit Arm code 
        .type   mult, %function  // 'mult' symbol is related to a function
        .global mult             // 'mult' is a global symbol
        .text                    // code will be put into the .text section
mult:
        mov     r1,r0
        lsl     r0,r0,#4
        add     r0,r1,r0
        bx      lr
        .end                     // end of program

 ./a.out
Result: 85
```

Please refer to the [GNU AS documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) for more details.

I am still looking for the root cause of your problem, which was actually fixed by using `.type   mult, %function`. Note that the exact same error does occur on a `Cortex-A7`Linux system, that is the fact that use are running a 64 bit Linux is not the issue.

Compiling two executables (with/without the .type directive) and comparing the outputs of the `readelf -a` command shows only one difference:

```
267c267
<    104: 00000534     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 mult
---
>    104: 00000534     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 mult
```

**UPDATE:**

The reason for your problem was pointed-out by [old_timer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16007/old-timer) - see his comment hereafter.

Your compiler is generating thumb2/T32 code by default, but your assembly code was arm/A32 by default since you did not specify which instruction set you where using. Compiling you original code with gcc `-marm` option (arm/A32) works fine:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10 -g -marm -o mult mult.c mult.s
./mult
Result: 85
```

The other option would be to force GNU AS to generate thumb2/T32 code in mult.s:

```
.thumb
.global mult

mult:
        mov     r1,r0
        lsl     r0,r0,#4
        add     r0,r1,r0
        bx      lr

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-10 -g -o mult mult.c mult.s
./mult
Result: 85
```

For more details on thumb2/T32, arm/A32 and interwork code, see [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/b/Overview-of-the-ARM-Architecture/A64--A32--and-T32-instruction-sets) and [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0471/m/interworking-arm-and-thumb).

Comment: Interestingly, the error does not occur on ARM-FreeBSD using the LLVM tool chain.

Comment: The `.type` directive does make a difference, but it's mostly related to whether the function is routed though the PLT or not.  I suppose OP implicitly built a PIE and thus this difference came to play.

Comment: Thanks. This may be time for me to go though [Ian Lance Taylor's 20 part Linker posts](https://lwn.net/Articles/276782/)...

Comment: the label needs to be marked as a function, the C compiler is likely generating thumb, and this code, didnt have a .thumb in it so was likely built as arm so there is a interwork problem.  almost none of that extra stuff was required, either a .type function or .thumb and a .thumb_func would have worked too.

Comment: @old_timer: you should probably promote your comment to an answer - thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Frant just added an answer.  Like the last time you basically had this one, I just added excess verbage.

Comment: @old_timer: Using `.thumb` in the original code is sufficient. Yes, the other stuff is not required, but still useful for documenting  what the exact target is IMHO, but I agree this is subjective.

Comment: .thumb is not sufficient if there is some arm mode code calling this function.  For this specific program yes, assuming that is what the bug is, .thumb is the minimum solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221275/discussion-between-frant-and-old-timer).